# XPath expressions instead of CSS selectors in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

For example the `document.querySelectorAll` works with CSS selectors, but how can I use XPath expressions instead?

Comment: there is an issue open, is it related to your requirement? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/537

Comment: yes,exactly!thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They just released this feature :)

**page.xpath(expression)**

> expression `<string>` Expression to evaluate
>
> returns:`<Promise<?ElementHandle>>` Promise which resolves to
> ElementHandle pointing to the page element.

check it out [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexpathexpression)

Comment: This feature is a moving target! It just got [renamed](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/commit/f183664d0f187649671d8d0086cbb016e0b24651) from `xpath` to `$x`.

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: page.$x is not a function`

Comment: @toing_toing that happens. But you can solve it as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474929/5131858
const featureArticle = (await page.$x("//a[text()='abc.com']"))[0];
const text = await page.evaluate(el => {return el.textContent;}, featureArticle);

Answer (score 1):

This is an [existing issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/537) open on puppeteer's git repo.

Track the progress here : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/537