# How to use xpath in chrome headless+puppeteer evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, puppeteer

How can I use `$x()` to use [xpath expression](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) inside a [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) ?

As far as `page` is not in the same context, I tried `$x()` directly (like I would do in chrome dev tools), but no cigar.

The script goes in timeout.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`$x()` is not a standard JavaScript method to select element by XPath. `$x()` it's only a [helper in chrome devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities). They claim this in the documentation:

> Key point: These functions only work when you call them from the Chrome DevTools Console. They won't work if you try to call them in your scripts.

And `page.evaluate()` is treated here as a "scripts on the page".

You have two options:

1. **Use [`document.evaluate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)**

Here is a example of selecting element (*featured article*) inside `page.evaluate()`:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        // $x() is not a JS standard -
        // this is only sugar syntax in chrome devtools
        // use document.evaluate()
        const featureArticle = document
            .evaluate(
                '//*[@id="mp-tfa"]',
                document,
                null,
                XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
                null
            )
            .singleNodeValue;

        return featureArticle.textContent;
    });

    console.log(text);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

2. **Select element by Puppeteer `page.$x()` and pass it to `page.evaluate()`**

This example achieves the same results as in the 1. example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    // await page.$x() returns array of ElementHandle
    // we are only interested in the first element
    const featureArticle = (await page.$x('//*[@id="mp-tfa"]'))[0];
    // the same as:
    // const featureArticle = await page.$('#mp-tfa');

    const text = await page.evaluate(el => {
        // do what you want with featureArticle in page.evaluate
        return el.textContent;
    }, featureArticle);

    console.log(text);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48476356/3708596) is a related question how to inject `$x()` helper function to your scripts.

Comment: Do you know a way to add scripts to load some custom functions in `evaluate()` ? Not found `include` or similar  on https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: @wam Write a new question with more clarification of your problem, and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on using [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression), you can simply pass the result to [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
const example = await page.evaluate(element => {
  return element.textContent;
}, (await page.$x('//*[@id="result"]'))[0]);
```