# Is there a way to add script to add new functions in evaluate() context of chrome+puppeeter?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, puppeteer

Based on this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448586/how-to-use-xpath-in-chrome-headlesspuppeteer-evaluate/48474929?noredirect=1#comment83945687_48474929), is there a way (like with casperjs/phantomjs) to add our custom functions in `page.evaluate()` context?

By example, include a file with a helper function `x` to call an Xpath function : `x('//a/@href')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register helper functions to run in the browser context in separate `page.evaluate()` calls. [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) looks tempting, but it [doesn't have access to browser context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer) (and you need the `document` object).

Here is an example of registering helper functions like `$x()` in the browser context:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const addHelperFunctions = () => {
    window.$x = xPath => document
        .evaluate(
            xPath,
            document,
            null,
            XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
            null
        )
        .singleNodeValue;
};

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await page.evaluate(addHelperFunctions);

    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        // $x() is now available
        const featureArticle = $x('//*[@id="mp-tfa"]');

        return featureArticle.textContent;
    });
    console.log(text);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

---

You can also keep helpers in a separate file and inject them into the browser context using [`page.addScriptTag()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions).

Here is an example of it:

`helperFunctions.js`

```js
window.$x = xPath => document
    .evaluate(
        xPath,
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
        null
    )
    .singleNodeValue;
```

And use it:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await page.addScriptTag({ path: './helperFunctions.js' });

    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        // $x() is now available
        const featureArticle = $x('//*[@id="mp-tfa"]');

        return featureArticle.textContent;
    });
    console.log(text);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on [casperjs](/questions/tagged/casperjs) `getElementByXPath()` and `getElementsByXPath()`. The advantage is that we can use an xpath expression against a particular node (second argument).

```
window.$x = xPath => document
    .evaluate(
        xPath,
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
        null
    )
    .singleNodeValue;

window.getElementByXPath = function getElementByXPath(expression, scope) {
    scope = scope || document;
    var a = document.evaluate(expression, scope, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    if (a.snapshotLength > 0) {
        return a.snapshotItem(0);
    }
};

window.getElementsByXPath = function getElementsByXPath(expression, scope) {
    scope = scope || document;
    var nodes = [];
    var a = document.evaluate(expression, scope, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < a.snapshotLength; i++) {
        nodes.push(a.snapshotItem(i));
    }
    return nodes;
};
```

Real life code sample :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://99bitcoins.com/bitcoin-rich-list-top100/#addresses', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.addScriptTag({ path: './helperFunctions.js' });

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        var obj = {};
        var data = getElementsByXPath('//table[@class="t99btc-rich-list"]//tr');
        for (var i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
           obj[i] = {
               "hash": getElementByXPath('./td/a', data[i]).innerText,
               "balance": getElementByXPath('./td[3]', data[i]).innerText
           }
        }

        return obj;

    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    await browser.close();

})();
```