# Looking for a way to write custom Puppeteer commands

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, nightwatch.js, puppeteer

Previously using Nightwatch.js I was able to create custom Nightwatch commands: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/extending-nightwatch/custom-commands.md

I'm wondering if there is anything that exists like this for Puppeteer-- the closest thing I've seen is: [Is there a way to add script to add new functions in evaluate() context of chrome+puppeeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476356/is-there-a-way-to-add-script-to-add-new-functions-in-evaluate-context-of-chrom)

But it's still far away from what I want. I would like to be able to call `page.commonAction(...)` instead of

```
page.x();
page.y();
page.z();
```

Comment: found a way yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create your own script with functions you can call. For example, I have a myFunctions.js in the same folder, from which I name

```
const mf = require('./myFunctions.js');
```

Inside the myFunctions.js I have, for example, this function:

```
async function verifyElementPresent(page, selector) {
  let verifySelector = await page.$(selector);
  if (verifySelector !== null) {
    console.log(found('> OK - Element present'));
  } else {
    console.log(notfound('>>> ERROR - Element not present: ' + selector));
  }
}
```

So now, in my Puppeteer script all I have to do is write:

```
mf.verifyElementPresent(page, '#headerTitle');
```

And it'll print in console the result.

Hope this helps.