# How do I get the value of an element in headless chrome?

Tags: puppeteer

I ran the following code:

```
await page.goto("http://github.com/", { "waitUntil": "networkidle2" });
let divs = await page.evaluate(() => $("div"));
```

But this throws the following error:

`Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

But when I check, it is defined:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`$()` is not a standard function in JS, it's only a helper in [Chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference) (`page.evaluate` is not the same environment as Chrome Devtools):

> Note: This API is only available from within the console itself. You cannot access the Command Line API from scripts on the page.

You should use instead [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Here is working example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://github.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  const textOfFirstDiv = await page.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelector('div').textContent
  );
  console.log(textOfFirstDiv);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

---

Edit

You choose unfortunate example to explain your problem. If you want to extract JS value from page use it simply like this (Wikipedia has custom `Geo` value in `window` object)

```js
await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org');
const geo = await page.evaluate(() => Geo);
console.log(geo);
```

Comment: I need to read the value of a variable such as `$`. I'm not trying to get DOM elements. It was just an example. I do I read the value of a variable?

Comment: @AskYous I hope now I answered a question you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah it's better, but in my question, I tried to read the value of `$('div')` but puppeteer said `$ is not defined` while it actually was defined. So why can't I read the value of the variable `$` on github.com using puppeteer? I used this code: `await page.evaluate(() => $);`. This was my initial question.

Comment: @AskYous GitHub doesn't have any `$` function, I told you - It's only a helper in devtools.

Comment: sorry I'm really confused now. When I go to GitHub, I typed `$` in the console and it **is** a function: https://i.imgur.com/RoxjQJg.png. I'm missing something.

Comment: @AskYous correct my terrible mistake in a question: it was `x()` but should be `$()`

Comment: Ooooh... I can call **only** standard functions and variables in puppeteer.evaluate?

Comment: @AskYous Command Line API functions belong only to DevTools (GUI in normal Chorme). This question has the same roots as yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448586/how-to-use-xpath-in-chrome-headlesspuppeteer-evaluate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166160/discussion-between-askyous-and-everettss).