# how to use puppeteer click() with xpath, web testing

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to click on element with this code:

```
test('no existed user try', async() => {
   await page.click($x('//*[contains (text(), "people")]'))
})
```

It returns me an error `$x is not a function`

how to use xpath correct with click ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use xpath in chrome headless+puppeteer evaluate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448586/how-to-use-xpath-in-chrome-headlesspuppeteer-evaluate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 test('no existed user try', async() => {    
    const elements = await page.$x('//*[contains (text(), "people")]');
    await elements[0].click();
 });
```