# Puppeteer/Evaluation: Problem with using $x in a puppeteer evaluation script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

This following code is meant to grab an elemtn via xpath but I get the following error:

Code:

```
    async main() {
        await this.initBrowser();
        await this.curPage.goto('https://someurl.com/');
        await this.curPage.evaluate(() => {
            console.log($x('//*Some_Xpath_Query'));
        })
    };
```

Error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $x is not defined
```

Comment: Where did you define `$x`? Where does it come from?

Comment: `document.evaluate` is the browser API for XPath 1.0 evaluation. `$x` is not part of that API, it is only exposed in the browser development console.

Comment: Puppeteer provides `page.$x` for evaluating xpaths, so I'd just use that in place of `page.evaluate` + console code. Why do you need `$x` in the console specifically? What Chromium version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use xpath in chrome headless+puppeteer evaluate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448586/how-to-use-xpath-in-chrome-headlesspuppeteer-evaluate)